Ошибка TypeError: 'pygame.rect.Rect' object is not callable
Код игры, она запускается, но при попытке выстрелить выходить ошибка "TypeError: 'pygame.rect.Rect' object is not callable" что делать не знаю, подскажите кто может.
import pygame as pg 

pg.init()
pg.font.init()






title = "Kill him!"

game_over = False


bullet_speed = 50
bullet_pos = (125, 325)

fps = 60

width = 800
height = 480

red = (191, 23, 23)
black = (0, 0, 0)
white = (255, 255, 255)
yelow = (241, 245, 34)
green = (13, 143, 26)


player_x = 125
player_y = 325
player_widht = 100
player_height = 100
player_speed = 8
player_last_move = "right"



roof_rect = pg.rect.Rect(0, 0, 800, 125)
floor_rect = pg.rect.Rect(0, 400, 800, 125)
player_rect = pg.rect.Rect(125, 325, 100, 100)
#bullet_rect = pg.rect.Rect(125, 325, 15, 5)
right_rect = pg.rect.Rect(801, 240, 5, 500)
bullit = pg.rect.Rect(player_x, player_y, 10, 10)



player_rect.x = player_x
player_rect.y = player_y




bullet = pg.image.load("bullet.png")
background = pg.image.load("grass.png")
player = pg.image.load("shooter2.png")
player = pg.transform.scale(player, (90, 105))





pg.mouse.set_visible(False)
screen = pg.display.set_mode([width, height])
pg.display.set_caption(title)
screen.blit(player, (player_rect))

class snaryad():
    def __init__(self, player_x, player_y, radius, color, facing):
        self.player_x = player_x
        self.player_y = player_y
        self.radius = radius
        self.color = color
        self.facing = facing
        self.vel = 8 * facing

    def draw(self, screen):
        pg.draw.circle(screen, self.color, (self.x, self.y), self.radius)

snaryad = pg.rect.Rect(player_x, player_y, 10, 10)

clock = pg.time.Clock()



bullets = []

for bullit in bullets:
    bullit.draw(screen)


running = True
while running:
    for event in pg.event.get():
        if event.type == pg.QUIT:
            running = False
            continue

    for bullit in bullets:
        if bullit.x < 800 and bullit.x > 0:
            bullit.x += bullit.vel
        else:
            bullets.pop(bullets.index(bullit))

    screen.blit(background,(0, 0))
    screen.blit(background,(320, 0))
    screen.blit(background,(640, 0))
    screen.blit(background,(0, 320))
    screen.blit(background,(320, 320))
    screen.blit(background,(640, 320))
    screen.blit(player, (player_rect))





    if not game_over:

        keys = pg.key.get_pressed()

        if keys[pg.K_f]:
            if player_last_move == "right":
                facing = 1
            else:
                facing = -1
                f
            if len(bullets) < 10:
                bullets.append[snaryad(round(player_x + player_widht // 2),
                 round(player_y + player_height // 2), 5, yelow, facing)]
        if keys[pg.K_a] and player_rect.x > 5:
            player_rect.x -= player_speed
            player_last_move = "left"
        elif keys[pg.K_d] and player_rect.x < 800 - player_rect.width - 5:
            player_rect.x += player_speed
            player_last_move = "right"
        elif keys[pg.K_w] and player_rect.y > 5:
            player_rect.y -= player_speed
        elif keys[pg.K_s] and player_rect.y < 480 - player_rect.height - 5:
            player_rect.y += player_speed



        clock.tick(fps)

    pg.display.flip()



class snaryad(): — snaryad = pg.rect.Rect( — вы уж определитесь, чем конкретно должен быть snaryad, он не может быть двумя разными вещами одновременно
